# What's the most proper way to remove an already deleted branch from tab-completion history?

Tags: git, bash, tab-completion

I can't exactly remember the events that led me to my current scenario, but it happened *something* similar to this:

- had a branch named `2-dev-inprogress`
- changed branch name of `2-dev-inprogress` to `2-dev-wip` using:

  - `git branch -mv 2-dev-inprogress 2-dev-wip`

My problem is that when i am in another branch and want to checkout `2-dev-wip` by using tab-completion (as usual), it only completes `2-dev-`, and gives me two options:

- `2-dev-inprogress`
- `2-dev-wip`

Anybody out there know some specific surgery to remove that `2-dev-inprogress` branch from tab-completion history? Only thing I've tried so far is commenting out `source ~/.git-completion.bash` in my .bash_profile and restart iTerm, but no luck. I also snooped around the .git directory, but got scared thinking I would fudge something up beyond repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have a remote branch named `2-dev-inprogress`?  If so you have to remove this branch or prevent git-completion of remote branches by commenting out the remote checks in /etc/bash_completion.d/git

Comment: Yep!: heroku/2-dev-inprogress. I probably have to do a `git push wip 2-dev-wip:2-dev-inprogress -f`

Comment: I was wrong about `git push wip 2-dev-wip:2-dev-inprogress -f`. I didn't read this post thoroughly enough. The correct command was `git push wip :2-dev-inprogress` to toast it, just like Michael's answer suggested above: "you have to remove this branch...". Now tab-completion is spot-on when checking out `2-dev-wip`. Thank you so much for the tip Michael.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer makes sense, but did not work in my situation.  If the remote branch no longer exists, then you may additionally need to prune.  I used [Seth Robertson's suggestion](http://sethrobertson.github.com/GitBestPractices/) to clean up my system and get rid of many branches all at once: `git remote | xargs -n1 git remote prune`.  This can happen if another person deleted the remote branch(es) or in my case if you did it from another machine.

Comment: Why `git remote | xargs -n1 git remote prune` instead of just `git fetch -p`?

Comment: True, `-p` should work just fine. Though I suspect it wasn't existing at the time yet.

Comment: I had forgotten about `git remote prune` and I now use `git fetch --prune`.  Not sure why I didn't see that @Jeff had commented, but @Błażej is right and I have upgraded git a number of times since then (I think I had an older cygwin version back in 2012 (older even than 2012))